# ios- UIButton not work in the custom view(UIViewX)

Tags: ios, swift, animation, view, uibutton

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

create a UIViewX in the View Controller or 
add UIButton on custom view(UIViewX). And IBAction is print(" test ")

Everything work good.

But...

When add UIButton on custom view(UIViewX) and add animation code with UIViewX, button does't work if I press it

how to fix it that can response print(" test ")?

Thanks in advance.

Here is animation code :

```
var currentColorArrayIndex = -1
var colorArray:[(color1: UIColor, color2: UIColor)] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    colorArrayFunction()
    backgroundAnimate()
}
```

[colorArrayFunction & backgroundAnimate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnqS1.png)

Here is UIViewX code :

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable
class UIViewXXXXX: UIView {

// MARK: - Gradient

@IBInspectable var firstColor: UIColor = UIColor.white {
    didSet {
        updateView()}}

@IBInspectable var secondColor: UIColor = UIColor.white {
    didSet {
        updateView()}}

@IBInspectable var horizontalGradient: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        updateView()}}

override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
    get {
        return CAGradientLayer.self}}

func updateView() {
    let layer = self.layer as! CAGradientLayer
    layer.colors = [ firstColor.cgColor, secondColor.cgColor ]

    if (horizontalGradient) {
        layer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        layer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    } else {
        layer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        layer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
    }}

// MARK: - Border

@IBInspectable public var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear {
    didSet {
        layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor}}

@IBInspectable public var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet {
        layer.borderWidth = borderWidth}}

@IBInspectable public var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet {
        layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    }
}

// MARK: - Shadow

@IBInspectable public var shadowOpacity: CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet {
        layer.shadowOpacity = Float(shadowOpacity)}}

@IBInspectable public var shadowColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear {
    didSet {
        layer.shadowColor = shadowColor.cgColor}}

@IBInspectable public var shadowRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet {
        layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius}}

@IBInspectable public var shadowOffsetY: CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet {
        layer.shadowOffset.height = shadowOffsetY}}}
```

Comment: Could you help us? Your code isn't really anything that can let us *duplicate* the issue. Specifically - and I'm using this word, um, specifically :-) - *What* are you trying to do? What are you seeing happening?  I'm counting *TEN* `IBInspectable` properties in your code - way too many, as it creates "noise" for identifying the issue. Any chance you can narrow it down? Pretend that I'm (a) a newbie at this and (b) wish to copy/paste your code to *duplicate* whatever problem you are having. Thanks!

Comment: This may be happening due to UIViewX's user interaction not enable. You must required to enable user interaction of UIViewX. Common thing is if you disable user interaction of superview then it's affected to subviews also and subview's user interaction sometimes disable.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I had solved that is no using "UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction"